# list-style-none + background-image = margin doesn't work?

Tags: css, list, styles, background-image, margin

I'm styling a list and need to set the margins precisely for it to look nice. But I'm using `list-style-none` and a `background-image` for each `<li>` element and it seems to make the `margin` property totally useless Oo

Well, nothing else to say, here is an exemple: http://symael.servhome.org/buglist.html

The problem is obvious: the padding and margin are the same for every `<ul>` on the page but in the "tree" div there is style  for the `<li>` elements. It seems to activate a default margin or somewhat...

Anybody knows how to solve this problem ? The aim is to have the "+" or "-" below the folder at the top... Yes, it's as simple as that :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the margin. The padding of the `li`s are pushing its children further to the right. You should decrease the padding:

```css
#tree li {
    padding-left: 18px;
}
#tree li a {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: How do I place the text well then ?
EDIT: Placed a margin on the `a` elements, I don't know how I didn't think of that >.<